# How do I programmatically find out my PermGen space usage?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm-hotspot, permgen

I'm trying to diagnose a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen Space` error when running on Sun's Hotspot JVM, and would like to know how much PermGen space my program is using at various points. Is there a way of finding out this information programmatically?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Iterator<MemoryPoolMXBean> iter = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
{
    MemoryPoolMXBean item = iter.next();
    String name = item.getName();
    MemoryType type = item.getType();
    MemoryUsage usage = item.getUsage();
    MemoryUsage peak = item.getPeakUsage();
    MemoryUsage collections = item.getCollectionUsage();
}
```

This will give you all types of memory. You are interested in "Perm Gen" type.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I am taking the MemoryPoolMXBean where name.equalsIgnoreCase("Perm Gen").

Answer (score 3):

Try [`ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getMemoryPoolMXBeans%28%29).

Comment: Thank you for getting me started.